# Get Annotation parameter from ActiveAnnotation

Tags: xtend

I'm trying to implement a parameterized ActiveAnnotation and try to get the supplied annotations.

```
@Active(ExampleProcessor)
annotation ExampleAnnotation {
    val String value
}

class ExampleProcessor extends AbstractClassProcessor {
    override doRegisterGlobals(ClassDeclaration annotatedClass, extension RegisterGlobalsContext context)
    {
        val annotation = ??
        annotation.value
    }
}
```

What I did

```
annotatedClass.annotations.filter(ExampleAnnotation).head.value
```

which sadly leads to a null pointer when using it like so:

```
@ExampleAnnotation("Hello!")
class MyClass { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`annotatedClass.annotations` consist of elements of `AnnotationReference` type, not `Class<?>`, you should look up a type for your class and then use it to filter out annotations, e.g.:

```
val annotation = annotatedClass.findAnnotation(ExampleAnnotation.findUpstreamType)
val value = annotation.getStringValue('value');
```